# What I should do to update if the table from the database keeps on changing

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a task and I am going to explain on what my work should be like.

First of all, I use the `$.get` method to get the total numbers of rows from the table in the database and show the value to the html file.

After ***1 hours*** or ***2 hours*** or ***2 days*** or longer,  the total number of rows from the table change...

What I should do to update the total number of rows in the html file other than refreshing the page or reloading the page?

my code is found below:

**calculatetotalattack.php**

```
<?php

   include 'config.php';
   $con = mysqli_connect ($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword) or die ('Error in connecting: ' . mysqli_error($con));

   //Select the particular database and link to the connection
   $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($con, $dbname ) or die('Select dbase error '. mysqli_error());
   //Make A SQL Query and link to the connection
   $totalattackview = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM attackview'); // get number of row from attackview

   //Calculate the total number of rows from the table
   $totalofrowsattack = mysqli_num_rows($totalattackview);

   echo $totalofrowsattack;

   mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Updating the Total Number of the total rows</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Cesium-1.34/ThirdParty/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="totalattack"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function totalAttacks(val) {
        $('#totalattack').html(val);
    }

    $.get({
        url: 'calculateTotalAttack.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: totalAttacks
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there ways ?

Comment: `$.get` to get a row count of the rows or setInterval/timeout to get the rows.

Comment: You need to dynamically add rows to your table in that case.

Comment: @Script47, I do not understand your sentence except the $.get part..

Answer (score 1):

You can just dynamically add rows or columns to your table in the html file and then display the data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    table, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>Click the button to add a new row at the first position of the table and then add cells and content.</p>

    <table id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <td>Row1 cell1</td>
        <td>Row1 cell2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row2 cell1</td>
        <td>Row2 cell2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row3 cell1</td>
        <td>Row3 cell2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var row = table.insertRow(0);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
        cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

> The insertRow() method creates an empty  element and adds it to a
>   table.

Use the setInterval()/ setTimeout() method to continously call the function to make it dynamic.

Also since you don't know when the rows/columns will increase, you can constantly monitor for any change in the no. of rows in table using setInterval() and if there are any changes make the table grow.

Answer (score 0):

U can use a time interval to call *totalAttacks()* each X time.

Here is the documetation: [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can run $.get function by timer, like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Updating the Total Number of the total rows</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/Cesium-1.34/ThirdParty/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="totalattack"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function totalAttacks(val) {
      $('#totalattack').html(val);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      var timer = setInterval(function() {
        $.get({
          url: 'calculateTotalAttack.php',
          dataType: 'text',
          success: totalAttacks
        });
    console.log('requesting  changes');
      }, 5000);       
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax with jquery to upload your data dynamically like

```
$document.ready(){

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "",
        data: {
            first_name: $("#namec").val(),
            last_name: $("#surnamec").val(),
            email: $("#emailc").val(),
            mobile: $("#numberc").val(),
            password: $("#passwordc").val()
        },
        success: function(response) {
            //dynamically add your data from here like make the new data equal to old one

        },
        error: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```